# Transpose table including headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, unpivot

I have a query I want transposed including headers. Cutdown example below:

```
SELECT 'Records' AS [Entity], COUNT([ContactID]) AS [ContactID],
        COUNT([FirstName]) AS [FirstName],
        COUNT([LastName]) AS [LastName],COUNT([Title]) AS [Title] 
FROM [all].[Account]
```

Here is an example I created in Excel to demonstrate the required outcome:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports lateral joins and the `values()` row constructor, you can unpivot and aggregate as follows:

```
select x.entity, count(x.val) records
from account a
cross apply (values ('contactid', a.contactid), ('firstname', a.firstname), ('last_name', a.lastname)) as x(entity, val)
group by x.entity
```

Some databases use `cross join lateral` instead of `cross apply`.

A more portable approach (although less efficient) is `union all`:

```
select 'contactid' entity, count(contactid) from account
union all
select 'firstname', count(firstname) from account 
union all
select 'lastname', count(lastname) from account
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that was close enough to what i required and was certainly more efficient  than what i originally had which was similar to your second suggestion.

Comment: Welcome @JSheldrake. If my answer properly responded to your question, then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check sign.

Answer (score 0):

In general (ANSI SQL) the task is not trivial. It depends on the number of columns and values in the initial table/query. Previous response with UNION ALL solves your task pretty good.

But as long as you have SQL server RDBMS, there is a PIVOT/UNVPIVOT to transpose almost every table/query:

```
-- suppose you have a table 
CREATE TABLE Account ([ContactID] varchar(10), [FirstName] varchar(10)
, [LastName] varchar(10),[Title] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO Account VALUES 
('Aaa', 'Bbb', 'Ccc','Ddd'), ('Eee', 'Fff', 'Ggg','Hhh')
, ('Qqq', 'Www', 'Rrr','Ttt'),  ('Zzz', 'Xxx', 'Vvv','Nnn')
, ('Mmm', 'Sss', 'Uuu','Ooo');
```

The result will be

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT 'Records' AS [EntityN], columnName as [Entity], columnValue
FROM [Account]
UNPIVOT
(
  columnValue
  FOR columnName IN (ContactID,FirstName, LastName, Title)
) unpivotQuery
) q
PIVOT
(
 COUNT(columnValue)
 FOR EntityN in (Records)
) pivotQuery;
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36a20d/17) to play around